# Reducing the min weight perfect matching problem to a T-join

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

My lecture notes for $T$-joins states:

> If $T = V$ then $T$ -joins of cardinality $V/2$
> are exactly the perfect matchings of $G$ = $(V ,E)$.
> So, the minimum weight perfect matching problem can be reduced to the minimum
> weight $T$ -join problem by adding a large constant to each edge weight (to get a degree
> of 1 for each vertex in a $T$-join.)

I agree with this but I don't see how adding a large constant to each edge weight restricts the degree of each vertex to 1 in the $T$-join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the algorithm is adding a large positive weight to each edge, the minimum weight $T$-join will have the minimum number of edges in it. Note that the least number of edges in a $T$-join for $T = V$ could be $|V|/2$. That is, each vertex has degree exactly $1$.

Comment: How does adding a large constant gaurantee that the $T$-join has the minimum number of edges in it?

Comment: @SVMteamsTool Suppose you add constant $c \gg |E| \cdot max_{e \in E} \{ w_e \}$, then any $T$-join with $k+1$ edges will have larger weight than any $T$-join with $k$ edges. Can you prove this statement?

Comment: Yes! That puts things into context, thanks!